# Python Django e-mail form example

Tags: python, html, django, forms, email

I wanted to make a contact form on my website. I can find PHP e-mail forms everywhere, but there are no Django examples. I have no idea how to do it myself, so I'm asking if there is anyone who could tell me from scratch - how to make an e-mail contact form on website using Django?

Comment: You can use the code in this github:
[https://github.com/jezdez/django-contact-form](https://github.com/jezdez/django-contact-form) or The a look [here](http://www.pydanny.com/simple-django-email-form-using-cbv.html) for a simple example.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

A simple example could be:

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from yourapp import views

urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^email/$',
        views.email,
        name='email'
        ),
    url(r'^thanks/$',
        views.thanks,
        name='thanks'
        ),
)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):

    from_email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    subject = forms.CharField(required=True)
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail, BadHeaderError
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from yourapp.forms import ContactForm

def email(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = ContactForm()
    else:
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            from_email = form.cleaned_data['from_email']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']
            try:
                send_mail(subject, message, from_email, ['admin@example.com'])
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
            return redirect('thanks')
    return render(request, "yourapp/email.html", {'form': form})

def thanks(request):
    return HttpResponse('Thank you for your message.')
```

**email.html**

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <div class="form-actions">
      <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If simplicity is important, [Formspree](https://formspree.io/) might be an alternative. They make it super easy.

You just need to insert something like this in your code:

```
<form action="https://formspree.io/your@email.com"
      method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="email" name="_replyto">
    <textarea name="message"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

Then you validate the e-mail, and you are ready to go.

For further information, [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6sI8Yq63SYM) explains how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

1. From django.conf.urls import patterns, url
2. From yourapp import views

**Example**

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^email/$',
        views.email,
        name='email'
        ),
    url(r'^thanks/$',
        views.thanks,
        name='thanks'
        ),
)
```