# Issue on sending message from contact page - Django 1.6

Tags: python, django

I have this method on my `views.py`:

```
def contact_us(request):
form = ContactUsForm()
d = {'form': form}
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ContactUsForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        Contact.objects.create(
            first_name=form.cleaned_data['first_name'],
            last_name=form.cleaned_data['last_name'],
            email=form.cleaned_data['email'],
            message=form.cleaned_data['message'],
        )
        try:
            send_mail(first_name,last_name,email,message,['kristian.koci@gmail.com'])
        except BadHeaderError:
            return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
        d['message'] = _('Thank You! We will contact you shortly')
    else:
        d['form'] = form

return render_to_response('profiles/contact_us.html', d,
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

This is the url:

http://beta.contratalos.com/profiles/contact_us/

I want to send that message to the recipient I've specified on `sned_mail` method.

But everytime I try it throws this error:

```
NameError: global name 'first_name' is not defined
File "apps/profiles/views.py", line 737, in contact_us
send_mail(first_name,last_name,email,message,['kristian.koci@gmail.com'])
```

Any ideas on what that could be?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not declaring the variable `first_name`, `last_name` anywhere.

The following code will help you.

```
    temp_contact=Contact.objects.create(
        first_name=form.cleaned_data['first_name'],
        last_name=form.cleaned_data['last_name'],
        email=form.cleaned_data['email'],
        message=form.cleaned_data['message'],
    )
    temp_contact.save()
    try:
       send_mail(temp_contact.first_name,temp_contact.last_name,temp_contact.email,temp_contact.message, ['kristian.koci@gmail.com'])
    except:
       ...
```

Edit:

The following code will help you send the right thing.

```
    temp_contact=Contact.objects.create(
        first_name=form.cleaned_data['first_name'],
        last_name=form.cleaned_data['last_name'],
        email=form.cleaned_data['email'],
        message=form.cleaned_data['message'],
    )
    temp_contact.save()
    try:
        email_subject = "Contact Registration - "+temp_contact.email
        email_content = "Name:"+temp_contact.first_name+" "+temp_contact.last_name+"\nContent:"+temp_contact.message
       send_mail(email_subject,email_content,temp_contact.email, ['kristian.koci@gmail.com'])
    except:
       ...
```

Comment: Thank you Siddhart, but now says: AssertionError: "to" argument must be a list or tuple =(

Comment: I think you are using the send_mail in an incorrect manner. send_mail('Subject here', 'Here is the message.', 'from@example.com',
    ['to@example.com'], fail_silently=False)

Comment: And the fields? I mean it should send these fields data, I just replace it with this?

Comment: I took this code from this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28400943/python-django-e-mail-form-example

Comment: Super Awesome! Thank you very much Siddhart!