# How to send a email from a form django

Tags: python, django, forms, email

As the title says i am trying to send a email from a form, but is not working:

As you can see:

```
<form method="POST" action=''>
      {% csrf_token %}
      <div class="control-group form-group">
        <div class="controls">
          <label>Nombre completo:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" required data-validation-required-message="Introduzca su nombre.">
          <p class="help-block"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group form-group">
        <div class="controls">
          <label>Asunto:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="asunto" required data-validation-required-message="Introduzca el asunto del correo.">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group form-group">
        <div class="controls">
          <label>Correo Electrónico:</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Introduzca su correo electrónico.">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group form-group">
        <div class="controls">
          <label>Mensaje:</label>
          <textarea rows="10" cols="100" class="form-control" id="contenido" required data-validation-required-message="Escriba su mensaje" maxlength="999" style="resize:none"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar mensaje</button>
    </form>
```

This is my view:

```
def contact(request):

contactdata = contactData.objects.get()
members = teamMembers.objects.filter(existencia=True)
templates = Templates.objects.get(isSelected=True)
categoria = Clasificacion.objects.filter(existencia=True)
enterprise = enterprisedata.objects.get()
content = request.POST.get('contenido', '')
name = request.POST.get('nombre', '')
email = request.POST.get('email', '')
subject = request.POST.get('asunto', '')
if request.method == 'POST' and email and name:
    send_mail(subject, content, email, ['kike1996@hotmail.com'], fail_silently=False)
contexto = {'categoria':categoria,'templates':templates,'members':members,
            'contactdata':contactdata,'enterprise':enterprise}
return render(request, 'contact/contact.html', contexto)
```

I am calling the form with the POST request, but is not sending anything!.

Hope you can help me, thank you!.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Django e-mail form example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28400943/python-django-e-mail-form-example)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to send mail then you have to configure this setting in your project's `settings.py` file

For example if you want to send email through your gmail account:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "your gmail address"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'your password'
EMAIL_PORT = '587'
```

And also remember to **`enable less secure apps`** in you google account for sending email.
 And in the view you can try like this:

```
if request.method == 'POST' and email and name:
    send_mail(subject, content, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, ['kike1996@hotmail.com'], fail_silently=False)
```

Answer (score 4):

Essentially this is the line of code that sends an email from djagno.

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

send_mail(subject, content, from_email, to_list, fail_silently=False)
```

The subject and content part are intuitive, then what remains is setting up the from_email and the to_list(which could even be 1 email in a list).

You've to define the following variables in your settings file.

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = smtp.gmail.com
EMAIL_HOST_USER = user@gsuiteaccount.com
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = password
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

Django permits the use of gsuite accounts for sending emails. To set up gsuit, go to your Google Account settings, find Security -> Account permissions -> Access for less secure apps, enable this option.

About this option: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255
Hope this gets you going.